# How to ajax multiply JSON files using document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

```
$("document").ready(
    function () {
        $.getJSON("French.json", function displayFromJson(french) {

            console.log(french.firstName)

        })
    },
    function () {
        $.getJSON("english.json", function displayFromJson(english) {
            console.log(english.lastName)
        })
    });
```

*French.json*

```
{
    "firstName": "Merci",
    "lastName": " Claudè"
}
```

*english.json*

```
{
    "firstName": "Gracias",
    "lastName": "Claude"
}
```

Comment: It might also runs on linux, where the filesystem path is case-sensitive, and the file name is `french.json`, and maybe you didn't include jquery or the path is just wrong. Read [ask] and create a [mcve] - Don't just dump your code and say that it doesn't work, you should explain what exactly is not working

Comment: Did you mean "multiple" instead of "multiply" in your title?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to call `ready` on the `document` object not on a `<document>` element. So pass `document` to jQuery, not the type selector `"document"`.

Second:

`ready()` accepts one and only one function so either:

1. Don't use `ready` (there's no need for it in the code you are using as you aren't manipulating the DOM)
2. Call `ready` twice and pass it one function each time
3. Call `ready` once and combine the two functions into one

---

```
$.getJSON("French.json", function displayFromJson(french) {
    console.log(french.firstName)
});
$.getJSON("english.json", function displayFromJson(english) {
    console.log(english.firstName)
});
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("French.json", function displayFromJson(french) {
        console.log(french.firstName)
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("english.json", function displayFromJson(english) {
        console.log(english.firstName)
    });
});
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("French.json", function displayFromJson(french) {
        console.log(french.firstName)
    });
    $.getJSON("english.json", function displayFromJson(english) {
        console.log(english.firstName)
    });
});
```

Comment: If I wanted to toggle between both getJson's how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Fire both requests in your `ready` callback

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $.getJSON("French.json", function displayFromJson(french) {
        console.log(french.firstName)
      })

      $.getJSON("english.json", function displayFromJson(english) {
        console.log(english.lastName)
      })
});
```